# スマートフォンでのp2p通信について。

Tags: network, ipアドレス, p2p

スマートフォンで、IP アドレス/ポートをお互いにわかっていて承認していれば、お互いがファイルを転送することは可能ですか？
それを、実装するにはどのような技術や知見が必要ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あなたがどのような p2p を想定しているのか読者にはわかりませんが

> IP アドレス/ポートをお互いにわかっていて承認していれば、

おそらくそこがスマホ p2p を稼働させるに最も解決困難なところでしょうが、全部解決済みとしてしまうのであれば、あと考えるべきことは少なくて

> 実装するにはどのような技術や知見が必要ですか？

新しい技術など必要ありません。スマホ上でサーバーソフトを動かすだけのことです。 `ftpd` であれ `httpd` であれスマホ上で動かせます。現に [ftpd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.primftpd) も [httpd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mj.android.httpd) も Google Play 上にて公開されています。